# Запрет перезаписи переменной

Tags: c++

У меня есть 4 переменных: `x y z i`.
Каждая из переменных, каждый раз перезаписывается из-за принятий сообщений от сервера. Как запретить перезапись переменных `x` и `y`? Т.е. 1 раз он записывает, следующие разы, нет.

Comment: Флажок отдельный использовать и при первой установке взводить, а при повторных проверять и отклонять изменения.

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan можете написать примерный код? Не знаю, даже какой "флажок"

Comment: @Insider, переменная типа `bool`. При значении `true` говорят, что флаг взведён.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вероятно, это уже не должны быть *просто* переменные и нужно писать какой-то «обвес». Самый элементарный — добавить условие. Например:

```
bool xset = false; // где-то на внешнем уровне

if (!xset) { 
    x = newx;
    xset = true;
}
```

Чуть посложнее — обернуть в функцию:

```
void setX(int newx) {
    static bool xset = false;
    if (!xset) { 
        x = newx;
        xset = true;
    }
}
```

Можно вовсе обернуть в класс переменную `x` и перегрузить оператор присваивания, в котором реализовать упомянутую выше логику и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

Можно логику обернуть в класс, вроде такого:

```
template<typename T>
class SetOnce
{
public:
    SetOnce() = default;

    // Это оператор присваивания. Он будет вызываться при каждой
    // попытке записи в переменную.
    SetOnce<T> &operator=(const T &value)
    {
        // Если переменная ещё не записана, то записываем.
        // Иначе -- оставляем старое значение.
        if ( !m_isSet ) {
            m_isSet = true;
            m_value = value;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    operator T() const
    {
        return m_value;
    }

private:
    T m_value = T();
    bool m_isSet = false; // Это "флажок".
};
```

Потом его можно использовать так:

```
int main()
{
    // Делаем переменную типа int, в которую можно записать значение
    // только один раз.
    SetOnce<int> i;

    i = 10;
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
    // Выведет 10.

    i = 20;
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
    // Всё ещё 10, т.к. 20 не было записано.

    return 0;
}
```